# Find connected device to Galaxy Tab - Android

Tags: android

I'm developing an app in which I must start a slideshow with some picture info. So far, so good. There's only one issue: I need to show one type of view when the device (galaxy tab) is connected to a TV (TV-Out) and another view if it's showing on the tab.

Example:

If is connected to TV: Show only the images on TV, no info.
If is not connected to TV: Show images plus info.

How can I find out if the device is plugged to a TV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I'm not sure as I don't have the Tab):

1. Add `uiMode` to [`android:configChanges`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) in your manifest.
2. Extend [`onConfigurationChanged(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) in your main Activity.
3. Inside it check [`Configuration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) for various flags.

Does `onConfigurationChanged()` gets called when you plug in the TV? Do any flags change?

Comment: actually I haven't been able to test it yet. This project got a low priority flag :) As soon as I'm able to test it I'll let you know. Best regards.